# Capture Analog Audio Output from a two-way radio?

Tags: audio

I am trying to record audio that is from a two way radio, which is equipped with a d-sub 15 pin accessory connector.  I know pin 2 outputs analog audio at -10 dBm @ 600 Ohms, so what do I need to do in order to use this signal?

[Service Manual for Radio With Pin Description](http://www.vertexradiogroup.org/folders/vx-4500/VX-4500_4600_UHF_SM_USA_EXP_EU_EC093U90B.pdf)

Comment: What were you planning on using to record the audio?

Comment: You will need the corresponding return connection of course.   Additionally I would add in a 600:600 Ohm line isolation transformer to eliminate hard to troubleshoot ground loops.  These are available from many audio component suppliers in cased or component form.

Answer (score 2):

-10dBm @ 600Ω (-10dBu) is a consumer level output, it should work fine with any line level input (e.g. PC soundcard line in, Hi-Fi line in).